# Best practice collecting info from parallel tasks

Tags: node.js

I'm starting my way in the node.js world.

I decided to learn more by building a monitor project, the user will input a domain and the monitor will run multiple parallel scans on the domain.

My question what is the best practice to run parallel tasks?
After running all scans how I can "know" when they finish and collect the info to a central place, where I can process and save the info/logs?

My best idea, for now, is using promises for each scan and then use Promise.all

```
const scan1 = require('./modules/scan1');
const scan2 = require('./modules/scan2');
const scan3 = require('./modules/scan3');

Promise.all([scan1, scan2, scan3]).then(function(values) {
    // Get the info here and final loginc
   console.log(values);
});
```

**The tricky question, if I want to grow and run 200 domains and each of this domain has different scans (uptime for example)?**

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable approach. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all Promise.all returns an array of the results of the promises in the order they are provided. What is your specific question?

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra, I was interested to know if there is a better approach from the one I wrote and wanted to know if I scan 200 domains, what is the best approach to "attach" each of the scans result to the source domain?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] what is the best practice to run parallel tasks? [...]
>
> **The tricky question, if I want to grow and run 200 domains and each of**
>   **this domain has different scans (uptime for example)?**

## Notes About Scaling :

> **· Vertical Scaling :** you scale by adding more power (CPU, RAM) to an existing machine.

If you have a powerful machine, then you could benefit of multi-threading, spawning a new processes that would perform a specific task (or group of tasks) per domain to be scanned. The more CPU power, the more domains you could simultaneously scan.

> **· Horizontal Scaling :**  you scale by adding more machines into your pool of resources.

If you want to work with a pool of machines, then I suggest that you have one that would act as the a master that assigns job queues to the others (slaves / workers).

---

### So first decide what scaling approach fits your own needs best...

There is a big difference if *you are going to run parallel tasks on different machines* or if *you are going to run the parallel tasks on the same machine*

You could even go "server-less" for performing certain tasks (combining [*Google cloud functions*](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/cloud-functions-serverless-platform-is-generally-available) or [*AWS Lambda*](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/))

---

Since you say you are interested in learning :

- **[Node.js : Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)**
- **[Redis](https://hackernoon.com/using-redis-with-node-js-8d87a48c5dd7)**
- **[node-ipc (npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc)**